# Doing a content search within an app

Tags: angular

I have a search written where I need to be able to search through the app's content. The service looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
   baseUrl: string = './demo/';
   //baseUrl: string = 'https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries';
   queryUrl: string = '?search=';

   constructor(private http: Http) { }

   search(terms: Observable<string>) {
      return terms.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
   }

   searchEntries(term) {
      return this.http
      .get(this.baseUrl + this.queryUrl + term)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

I tried it with that baseUrl: string pointing to a link (https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries). That works great! But obviously that is useless to me. I need it to be able to query through my actual site content dynamically. I have no idea how to make it find all HTML content and ignore ambiguous content such as the name of buttons for example.

I am using the code in this tutorial [here](https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/)

Any ideas? My Angular knowledge is extremely limited.

Comment: Where is the site content stored? You should do the search on the API side, not try to get the site to load itself again to see if it contains whatever text.

Comment: I agree. Any tutorial you can point me to where I can earn to do this? I know my way around AngularJS1 and had it working there just fine, but we're upgrading now

Comment: To answer your question, the content is stored in each component generating views in their respective templateUrl.

Comment: If the content only exists in the `.component` files then I don't know how you'd even do this. If you need to be able to search the site, it may make sense to restructure it so that the content comes from somewhere you can query it, e.g. in the backend.

Comment: I suppose I could move the content to jsons for UI/UX mockup purposes and showing the functionality. I still would need to figure out how to query a json file. DO I reference it in the baseUrl I posted in my code? Again, new to angular2(4)